# Ошибка "this.userRepository" is null

Tags: java, spring, crud

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем причина ошибки?

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private List<User> users;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService() {
        this.users = userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<User> getByLogin(@NonNull String login) {
        return users.stream()
                .filter(user -> login.equals(user.getLogin()))
                .findFirst();
    }

}
```

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

```
Error: Cannot invoke "com.hood.merch.security.repo_auth.UserRepository.findAll()" because "this.userRepository" is null
```

В таблице User находится один объект.

Comment: Ошибка указывает, что Spring не смог автоматически связать переменную `userRepository` с соответствующим репозиторием.  `UserRepository` у вас отмечен соответствующей Spring аннотацией `@Repository`?

Comment: Дело даже не в спринг. Ошибка возникает в конструкторе по умолчанию, который тут указан. Т.к. в конструкторе не указан `userRepository` то он инициализирован `null`. Это стандартное поведение java.  Спринг добирается до объекта после вызова конструктора и создания объекта.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, но при этом другой мой репозиторий схож по вызову и отличается только методом: `Optional<Product> findById(int i);`

Comment: @NowhereMan, не помогло(

Comment: @MrFylypenko все правильно написал. Чтобы зафиксить - передавайте UserRepository объект в конструктор (и, соответственно, перенесите `@Autowired` туда же) и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, то лучше всего вообще избавиться от Autowired и конструкторов (если конечно там не что-то специфичное), а юзать AllArgsConstructor, ну или RequiredArgsConstructor